# Removing horizontal space between vertical, staggered and overlapping pile of cards

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I'm trying to remove empty horizontal space between 12 vertical piles of cards.  I've got the cards stacking by rank (i.e., all the 3's are stacked nicely together, all the 4's stacked, etc.). Now I just need to reduce the horizontal space between each pile. Not sure why CSS Grid is adding all that unwanted space.

I tried adding the following extra CSS to further control the pile layouts but that just made things worse:

```
div.three { grid-column-start: three;  grid-column-end: four;}
div.four { grid-column-start: four;  grid-column-end: five;}
div.five { grid-column-start: five;  grid-column-end: six;}
div.six { grid-column-start: six;  grid-column-end: seven;}
div.seven { grid-column-start: seven;  grid-column-end: eight;}
div.eight { grid-column-start: eight;  grid-column-end: nine;}
div.nine { grid-column-start: nine;  grid-column-end: ten;}
div.ten { grid-column-start: ten;  grid-column-end: jack;}
div.jack { grid-column-start: jack;  grid-column-end: queen;}
div.queen { grid-column-start: queen;  grid-column-end: king;}
div.king { grid-column-start: king;  grid-column-end: ace;}
div.ace { grid-column-start: ace;  grid-column-end: ace-end;}
```

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/lenbo41/nvu5jyzt/4/

Need to see the 4 pile to the right of the 3-pile, the 5-pile to the right of the 4-pile, etc., without large empty gaps in between the piles.

```css
#p1-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [three] 100px [four] 100px [five] 100px [six] 100px [seven] 100px [eight] 100px [nine] 100px [ten] 100px [jack] 100px [queen] 100px [king] 100px [ace] 100px [ace-end];
  grid-template-rows: [card1] 150px [card2] 150px [card3] 150px [card4] 150px [card5] 150px [card6] 150px [card7] 150px [row-end];
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  background-color: beige;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 510px;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

div.card1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 11;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

div.card2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 12;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

div.card3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: -200px;
  z-index: 13;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

div.card4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 14;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

div.card5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 160px;
  left: -400px;
  z-index: 15;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

div.card6 {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: -500px;
  z-index: 16;
  background-color: darkblue;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

div.card7 {
  position: relative;
  top: 220px;
  left: -600px;
  z-index: 17;
  background-color: purple;
  opacity: 0.80;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1-grid">
  <div class="three card1">3H</div>
  <div class="three card2">3D</div>
  <div class="three card3">3C</div>
  <div class="three card4">3H</div>
  <div class="three card5">3D</div>
  <div class="three card6">3C</div>
  <div class="three card7">3C</div>

  <div class="four card1">4H</div>
  <div class="four card2">4S</div>
  <div class="four card3">4C</div>
  <div class="four card4">4D</div>
  <div class="four card5">4S</div>
  <div class="four card6">4C</div>
  <div class="four card7">4D</div>

  <div class="five card1">5H</div>
  <div class="five card2">5D</div>
  <div class="five card3">5C</div>
  <div class="five card4">5H</div>
  <div class="five card5">5D</div>
  <div class="five card6">5C</div>
  <div class="five card7">5C</div>

  <div class="six card1">6H</div>
  <div class="six card2">6S</div>
  <div class="six card3">6C</div>
  <div class="six card4">6D</div>
  <div class="six card5">6H</div>
  <div class="six card6">6S</div>
  <div class="six card7">6C</div>

  <div class="seven card1">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card2">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card3">7C</div>
  <div class="seven card4">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card5">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card6">7C</div>
  <div class="seven card7">7C</div>

  <div class="eight card1">8H</div>
  <div class="eight card2">8S</div>
  <div class="eight card3">8C</div>
  <div class="eight card4">8D</div>
  <div class="eight card5">8S</div>
  <div class="eight card6">8C</div>
  <div class="eight card7">8D</div>

  <div class="nine card1">9H</div>
  <div class="nine card2">9D</div>
  <div class="nine card3">9C</div>
  <div class="nine card4">9H</div>
  <div class="nine card5">9D</div>
  <div class="nine card6">9C</div>
  <div class="nine card7">9C</div>

  <div class="ten card1">10H</div>
  <div class="ten card2">10S</div>
  <div class="ten card3">10C</div>
  <div class="ten card4">10D</div>
  <div class="ten card5">10S</div>
  <div class="ten card6">10C</div>
  <div class="ten card7">10D</div>

  <div class="jack card1">JH</div>
  <div class="jack card2">JD</div>
  <div class="jack card3">JC</div>
  <div class="jack card4">JH</div>
  <div class="jack card5">JD</div>
  <div class="jack card6">JC</div>
  <div class="jack card7">JC</div>

  <div class="queen card1">QH</div>
  <div class="queen card2">QS</div>
  <div class="queen card3">QC</div>
  <div class="queen card4">QD</div>
  <div class="queen card5">QH</div>
  <div class="queen card6">QS</div>
  <div class="queen card7">QC</div>

  <div class="king card1">KH</div>
  <div class="king card2">KD</div>
  <div class="king card3">KC</div>
  <div class="king card4">KH</div>
  <div class="king card5">KD</div>
  <div class="king card6">KC</div>
  <div class="king card7">KC</div>

  <div class="ace card1">AH</div>
  <div class="ace card2">AS</div>
  <div class="ace card3">AC</div>
  <div class="ace card4">AD</div>
  <div class="ace card5">AH</div>
  <div class="ace card6">AS</div>
  <div class="ace card7">AC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this the required layout: https://jsfiddle.net/73t6nhcq/?

Comment: Perfect kukkuz.  You are awesome. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Putting comments into an answer - you are using *relative positioning* to shift the *grid cells* from their positions and thereby stacking the cards and that makes it *tricky* to predict the final layout. You can try this:

- use the *column placement* rules that you already have for `div.three`, `div.four`,..., `div.ace`,
- place each `div.card1`, `div.card2`,..., `div.card7` element into rows 1,2,...,7 respectively,
- use `grid-auto-rows: 40px` instead of `grid-template-rows` and set the 150px card height on the `#p1-grid > div` to get the required effect.

See demo below:

```css
#p1-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [three] 100px [four] 100px [five] 100px [six] 100px [seven] 100px [eight] 100px [nine] 100px [ten] 100px [jack] 100px [queen] 100px [king] 100px [ace] 100px [ace-end];
  grid-auto-rows: 40px; /* default card row height */
  grid-column-gap: 10px; /* a column gap */
  background-color: beige;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 510px;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

#p1-grid > div {
  height: 150px; /* specify height of each card here */
}

/* row placement on each card */

div.card1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 1; /* place in row 1 */
}

div.card2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 12;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 2;  /* place in row 2 */
}

div.card3 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 13;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 3; /* place in row 3 */
}

div.card4 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 14;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 4; /* place in row 4 */
}

div.card5 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 5; /* place in row 5 */
}

div.card6 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 16;
  background-color: darkblue;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 6; /* place in row 6 */
}

div.card7 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 17;
  background-color: purple;
  opacity: 0.80;
  grid-row: 7; /* place in row 7 */
}

/* column placement */

div.three { grid-column-start: three;}
div.four { grid-column-start: four; }
div.five { grid-column-start: five; }
div.six { grid-column-start: six; }
div.seven { grid-column-start: seven; }
div.eight { grid-column-start: eight; }
div.nine { grid-column-start: nine; }
div.ten { grid-column-start: ten;  }
div.jack { grid-column-start: jack;  }
div.queen { grid-column-start: queen;  }
div.king { grid-column-start: king; }
div.ace { grid-column-start: ace; }
```

```html
<div id="p1-grid">
  <div class="three card1">3H</div>
  <div class="three card2">3D</div>
  <div class="three card3">3C</div>
  <div class="three card4">3H</div>
  <div class="three card5">3D</div>
  <div class="three card6">3C</div>
  <div class="three card7">3C</div>

  <div class="four card1">4H</div>
  <div class="four card2">4S</div>
  <div class="four card3">4C</div>
  <div class="four card4">4D</div>
  <div class="four card5">4S</div>
  <div class="four card6">4C</div>
  <div class="four card7">4D</div>

  <div class="five card1">5H</div>
  <div class="five card2">5D</div>
  <div class="five card3">5C</div>
  <div class="five card4">5H</div>
  <div class="five card5">5D</div>
  <div class="five card6">5C</div>
  <div class="five card7">5C</div>

  <div class="six card1">6H</div>
  <div class="six card2">6S</div>
  <div class="six card3">6C</div>
  <div class="six card4">6D</div>
  <div class="six card5">6H</div>
  <div class="six card6">6S</div>
  <div class="six card7">6C</div>

  <div class="seven card1">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card2">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card3">7C</div>
  <div class="seven card4">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card5">7H</div>
  <div class="seven card6">7C</div>
  <div class="seven card7">7C</div>

  <div class="eight card1">8H</div>
  <div class="eight card2">8S</div>
  <div class="eight card3">8C</div>
  <div class="eight card4">8D</div>
  <div class="eight card5">8S</div>
  <div class="eight card6">8C</div>
  <div class="eight card7">8D</div>

  <div class="nine card1">9H</div>
  <div class="nine card2">9D</div>
  <div class="nine card3">9C</div>
  <div class="nine card4">9H</div>
  <div class="nine card5">9D</div>
  <div class="nine card6">9C</div>
  <div class="nine card7">9C</div>

  <div class="ten card1">10H</div>
  <div class="ten card2">10S</div>
  <div class="ten card3">10C</div>
  <div class="ten card4">10D</div>
  <div class="ten card5">10S</div>
  <div class="ten card6">10C</div>
  <div class="ten card7">10D</div>

  <div class="jack card1">JH</div>
  <div class="jack card2">JD</div>
  <div class="jack card3">JC</div>
  <div class="jack card4">JH</div>
  <div class="jack card5">JD</div>
  <div class="jack card6">JC</div>
  <div class="jack card7">JC</div>

  <div class="queen card1">QH</div>
  <div class="queen card2">QS</div>
  <div class="queen card3">QC</div>
  <div class="queen card4">QD</div>
  <div class="queen card5">QH</div>
  <div class="queen card6">QS</div>
  <div class="queen card7">QC</div>

  <div class="king card1">KH</div>
  <div class="king card2">KD</div>
  <div class="king card3">KC</div>
  <div class="king card4">KH</div>
  <div class="king card5">KD</div>
  <div class="king card6">KC</div>
  <div class="king card7">KC</div>

  <div class="ace card1">AH</div>
  <div class="ace card2">AS</div>
  <div class="ace card3">AC</div>
  <div class="ace card4">AD</div>
  <div class="ace card5">AH</div>
  <div class="ace card6">AS</div>
  <div class="ace card7">AC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @L.Palmeri could you please accept / upvote answer and close the question too? Thank you!